# Not Equal to Comparison in Codeigniter Active records

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am quite confused with this error which i am receiving with this code

```
$this->db->order_by('uid','DESC')->where('type!=',"Admin")->get('user_profile',$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
```

Here is what I get the Error

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL      server version for the right syntax to use near ''Admin' ORDER BY `uid` DESC LIMIT 10' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`user_profile`) WHERE `type!=` 'Admin' ORDER BY `uid` DESC LIMIT 10

Filename: C:\wamp\www\proposal\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Comment: Try putting a space between `type` and `!=`

Comment: Sorry, After research on google and stackoverflow, I found the solution. Only One has to put space between operator and the field. In my case $this->db->where('type !=',"Admin")

Answer (score 6):

Try your query like this. Use single commas for Admin instead of double commas. And <> instead of  !=

```
$this->db
    ->where('type <>','Admin')
    ->order_by('uid','DESC')
    ->get('user_profile',$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
```

Comment: Quick note: Don't forget the space between the fieldname and the "<>", should be 'type <>' and not 'type<>'. The second one will fail.